# Authorization Oauth2.0 Add Additional Body Parameter

Tags: postman

I’m trying to migrate an authorization request into the authorization at the Postman collection level. The request body has an additional parameter for account_id that needs to be passed.

[image]

I’m unable to find a way to pass this additional parameter when using Oauth 2.0 client credentials flow. Is there a way to include this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add a new header. I don't think this is supported on the collection level, but a workaround is to use a pre-request script on the collection level:

```js
const Header = require('postman-collection').Header
pm.request.headers.add(new Header(`account_id:${pm.environment.get('et_mid')}`))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! The pre-request scripts do not appear to execute prior to the Authorization call. I ran a quick test and am unable to see the added header. I followed by  adding a quick console.log statement and watched the console. The statement was only logged for requests and not for the authorization. I had considered moving the authorization entirely to a pre-request script and set checks based on the token TTL to determine when to execute however I was hoping for something cleaner.

Comment: @AaronCates: yeah, I think you're right there, you'd need to move more parts and then it becomes more messy. Perhaps the very first request in the collection could be the one to get the token, then in Scripts, you save the token in the environment for reuse later in other requests. It's still not ideal, but I can't think of a better solution right now.

Comment: Agreed. Thanks for helping me think through it!